# Indexing nested JSON array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have the following JSON example with an array under `"results"` that contains two objects. It can include hundreds of objects under the `"results"` array with the same keys and different values.

I do not have access to change this JSON file.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "title": "Information Collection Requests; Direct Loan Servicing-Regular; and Servicing Minor Program Loans",
      "type": "Notice",
      "abstract": "In accordance with the Paperwork Reduction Act (PRA) requirement, the Farm Service Agency (FSA) is requesting comments from all interested individuals and organizations on a revision of two currently approved information collection requests, Direct Loan Servicing--Regular and Servicing Minor Program Loans, respectively. In the Direct Loan Servicing--Regular, the information is used to determine borrower compliance with loan agreements, assist the borrower in achieving business goals, and regular servicing of the loan account such as graduation, subordination, partial release, use of proceeds, and consent. In Servicing Minor Program Loans, the information collected is used to perform routine and special servicing actions for loans authorized and serviced under FSA's Minor Loan Program.",
      "document_number": "2023-05464",
      "html_url": "https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2023/03/17/2023-05464/information-collection-requests-direct-loan-servicing-regular-and-servicing-minor-program-loans",
      "pdf_url": "https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/FR-2023-03-17/pdf/2023-05464.pdf",
      "public_inspection_pdf_url": "https://public-inspection.federalregister.gov/2023-05464.pdf?1678970722",
      "publication_date": "2023-03-17",
      "agencies": [
        {
          "raw_name": "DEPARTMENT OF AGRICULTURE",
          "name": "Agriculture Department",
          "id": 12,
          "url": "https://www.federalregister.gov/agencies/agriculture-department",
          "json_url": "https://www.federalregister.gov/api/v1/agencies/12",
          "parent_id": null,
          "slug": "agriculture-department"
        },
        {
          "raw_name": "Farm Service Agency",
          "name": "Farm Service Agency",
          "id": 157,
          "url": "https://www.federalregister.gov/agencies/farm-service-agency",
          "json_url": "https://www.federalregister.gov/api/v1/agencies/157",
          "parent_id": 12,
          "slug": "farm-service-agency"
        }
      ],
      "excerpts": "In accordance with the Paperwork Reduction Act (PRA) requirement, the Farm Service Agency (FSA) is requesting comments from all interested individuals and organizations on a revision of two currently approved information collection requests, Direct..."
    },
    {
      "title": "Notice of Funding Opportunity for the Socially Disadvantaged Groups Grant for Fiscal Year 2023",
      "type": "Notice",
      "abstract": "This notice announces that the Rural Business-Cooperative Service (RBCS, Agency), a Rural Development (RD) agency of the United States Department of Agriculture (USDA), invites applications for grants under the Socially Disadvantaged Groups Grant (SDGG) program for Fiscal Year (FY) 2023. This notice is being issued to allow applicants sufficient time to leverage financing, prepare and submit their applications, and give the Agency time to process applications within FY 2023. A total of $3,000,000 in grant funding will be available for FY 2023. Successful applications will be selected by the Agency for funding and subsequently awarded to the extent that funding may ultimately be made available through appropriations. All applicants are responsible for any expenses incurred in developing and submitting their applications.",
      "document_number": "2023-05441",
      "html_url": "https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2023/03/17/2023-05441/notice-of-funding-opportunity-for-the-socially-disadvantaged-groups-grant-for-fiscal-year-2023",
      "pdf_url": "https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/FR-2023-03-17/pdf/2023-05441.pdf",
      "public_inspection_pdf_url": "https://public-inspection.federalregister.gov/2023-05441.pdf?1678970718",
      "publication_date": "2023-03-17",
      "agencies": [
        {
          "raw_name": "DEPARTMENT OF AGRICULTURE",
          "name": "Agriculture Department",
          "id": 12,
          "url": "https://www.federalregister.gov/agencies/agriculture-department",
          "json_url": "https://www.federalregister.gov/api/v1/agencies/12",
          "parent_id": null,
          "slug": "agriculture-department"
        },
        {
          "raw_name": "Rural Business-Cooperative Service",
          "name": "Rural Business-Cooperative Service",
          "id": 456,
          "url": "https://www.federalregister.gov/agencies/rural-business-cooperative-service",
          "json_url": "https://www.federalregister.gov/api/v1/agencies/456",
          "parent_id": 12,
          "slug": "rural-business-cooperative-service"
        }
      ],
      "excerpts": "This notice announces that the Rural Business-Cooperative Service (RBCS, Agency), a Rural Development (RD) agency of the United States Department of Agriculture (USDA), invites applications for grants under the Socially Disadvantaged Groups Grant..."
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the following code to get and display the values I need from each key in the array, as so:

```js
const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onload = function() {
  const myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

  let text = "";
  for (let i in myArr.results) {
    text += "<div class='fed-reg-container'><h2 class='title'>" + myArr.results[i].title + "</h2><p>" + myArr.results[i].type + "</p><p>" + myArr.results[i].agencies[0].raw_name + " Document # " + myArr.results[i].document_number + "</p><p>Posted on: " + myArr.results[i].publication_date + "</p><p>" + myArr.results[i].abstract + "</p><a class='fed-reg-button' href='" + myArr.results[i].html_url + "'>Read More</a></div>";
  }
  text += "";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
};
xmlhttp.open(
  "GET",
  "https://www.federalregister.gov/api/v1/documents.json?conditions%5Bagencies%5D%5B%5D=agriculture-department&conditions%5Bagencies%5D%5B%5D=federal-highway-administration&conditions%5Bagencies%5D%5B%5D=fish-and-wildlife-service&conditions%5Bagencies%5D%5B%5D=forest-service&conditions%5Bagencies%5D%5B%5D=interior-department&conditions%5Bagencies%5D%5B%5D=international-boundary-and-water-commission-united-states-and-mexico&conditions%5Bagencies%5D%5B%5D=land-management-bureau&conditions%5Bagencies%5D%5B%5D=national-highway-traffic-safety-administration&conditions%5Bagencies%5D%5B%5D=national-park-service&conditions%5Bagencies%5D%5B%5D=reclamation-bureau&conditions%5Bagencies%5D%5B%5D=environmental-protection-agency&conditions%5Bagencies%5D%5B%5D=council-on-environmental-quality&conditions%5Bagencies%5D%5B%5D=safety-and-environmental-enforcement-bureau&conditions%5Bagencies%5D%5B%5D=environment-office-energy-department&conditions%5Bcomment_date%5D%5Bgte%5D=05%2F01%2F2023&conditions%5Bcomment_date%5D%5Blte%5D=01%2F01%2F2050&conditions%5Bterm%5D=arizona&conditions%5Btype%5D%5B%5D=RULE&conditions%5Btype%5D%5B%5D=PRORULE&conditions%5Btype%5D%5B%5D=NOTICE",
  true
);
xmlhttp.send();
```

```css
.fed-reg-container {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.title {
  color: #fcb900;
}

.fed-reg-button {
  background-color: #fcb900;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Everything works great except one thing.

As you can see, my json has a nested array under `"agencies"` with multiple objects.

I'm trying to use indexing to grab each value under the `raw_name` of each object.

If I use `+ myArr.results[i].agencies[0].raw_name` it works for a single object. Could be `[0]` or `[1]`.

When I try to grab the second value like `+ myArr.results[i].agencies[0].raw_name + " - " + myArr.results[i].agencies[1].raw_name`, it breaks the whole code. I get nothing in return. Just a white page.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You need a nested loop to process all the agencies in the nested array.

Comment: `for (let j = 0; j < myArr.results[i].agencies.length; j++)`. Or `myArr.results[i].agencies.forEach(agency => ...)`

Comment: that's only true if there is a variable number of elements in each agencies array. your code doesn't seem to be incorrect, just a bit messy... but the computer never cared about messy. I'd start by converting your concatenation to a template string, to see if there are any unescaped chars messing up the string.

Comment: Ahhh, Ok. Thanks for the fast reply! Can you provide me with an example? I'm not sure where to put that. :)

Comment: @NicolásStraub This is clearly just one example, there's no reason to assume there will always be 2 agencies.

Comment: @NicolásStraub Intersting. I'm new with JavaScript so I'm not sure how to do that. Any pointers? I'll do some research on that.

Comment: sure, \`this is a template string, with an evaluated ${variable} inside it\`

Comment: @Barmar that's exactly what I said

Comment: @NicolásStraub Who was your comment addressed to? I thought you were suggesting that my `for` loop isn't needed because there are always 2 items.

Comment: like I said, it's only necesarry if you've got a variable number of items in your array. since the issue is that the app errors out, the size of the array isn't really relevant to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a nested loop to process all the agencies. You can use `map()` to loop over them and return an array of names, and `join()` to concatenate them with a delimiter.

```
  for (let i in myArr.results) {
    let agencies = myArr.results[i].agencies.map(a => a.raw_name).join(', ');
    text += "<div class='fed-reg-container'><h2 class='title'>" + myArr.results[i].title + "</h2><p>" + myArr.results[i].type + "</p><p>" + agencies + " Document # " + myArr.results[i].document_number + "</p><p>Posted on: " + myArr.results[i].publication_date + "</p><p>" + myArr.results[i].abstract + "</p><a class='fed-reg-button' href='" + myArr.results[i].html_url + "'>Read More</a></div>";
  }
```